# Input data Guestbook PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to create a guestbook with mysql database. I have no trouble display the sql data on my form.

But when im trying to input data my send button dosent work. I think the problem is in this code, but I cant find it. and have done the tutorial a couple of times.

I dont have any error messages. But this is some of the code. 
thanks

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['page'])){


    echo "

    <form action='guest_process.php' method='post'>

<p>Name: <input type='text' name='name'> </p>
<p>Email: <input type='text' name='email'> </p>
<p>Comment: </p>
    <p><textarea name='comment'></textarea></p>
    <hr />
    <p><input type='button' name='submit' value='Post Entry'></p>


    </form>

    ";





    }else{

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die ('Couldnt connet');
$db = mysql_select_db('guestbook');

$query = mysql_query('select * from guestbook order by id desc');
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($num_rows > 0){

    //display entries
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        echo "
        <p>
        <b>Name: </b>".$row['name']."

        </p>

        <p>
        <b>Email: </b>".$row['email']."

        </p>

        <p>
        <b>Comment: </b>".$row['comment']."
        </p>

        <p>
        <b>Date: </b>".$row['date']." | Time: ".$row['time']."
        </p>
        <hr />
        ";


        }


    } else{

        echo 'no entries in database';
        }

    }

?>
```

The guestbook is seperated in two php files.
This is the other page the guest_process.php

```
<?php

if($_post['submit']){

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die ('Couldnt connet');
$db = mysql_select_db('guestbook');

$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$comment = n12br($_POST['comment']);
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$time = date('H:i:s');

$query = mysql_query("insert into guestbook values('','$name','$email','$comment','$date','$time')");

header('Location: index.php');


}else { 
header ('Location: index.php');

}
?>
```

Comment: Allright I solved the problem
The submit button was wrong, (as many of you said)
The correct script is
<p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Post Entry'></p>

And on guest_process.php

In the comment variable i was using n12br insted of strip_tags
so the correct string is : 
$comment = strip_tags($_POST['comment']);

thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

use `<input type="submit" value="Post Entry">` instead of `<input type=button>`

Comment: The type= submit actually got the button work, but I  still cantput data in my database

Answer (score 0):

this is not good:

```
<input type =button name='submit' value='Post Entry'>
```

it should be:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Entry">
```

Comment: I was in to that to, but I get a syntax error when Im using the double quotes.

Comment: swap the double quotes with the single ones

Comment: the emphasis is on __input type="submit"__ instead of _input type="button"_

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no code to put anything in a database.

First you need to actually post something. You might think that this line does this, but it doesn't:

```
<input type =button name='submit' value='Post Entry'>
```

Apart from the fact you need `"` around the type, a "button" isn't actually something that does submitting. You'll need client-side code for that. You could better change it to

```
<input type="button" name='submit' value='Post Entry'>
```

You won'nt be there though. Now you need to take the info from the `$_POST` variable (try `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's in there), and put it in your database. You can find the appropriate commands for SQL and the php-mysql connection in your tutorial probably